# What is the amount of abstract algebra needed to study elliptic curves?

Tags: elliptic-curves, abstract-algebra

To be more specific, how much is needed to understand the book 'Rational points on elliptic curves' by Silverman?

Comment: A good handle at least on rings and modules is probably required. You will definitely need rings for the algebraic geometry side of it.

Comment: Thanks. Would you recommend having experience with complex analysis?

Comment: Complex analysis is definitely good, but I'm not sure it would be a requirement.

Answer (score 3):

This book has six chapters, and one needs perhaps different prerequisites for each chapter. For chapter $I$ and $II$, on geometry of cubic curves and points of finite order, just basic algebra is enough, together with plane curves (affine and projective). For elliptic curves over the complex numbers, a bit of complex analysis is required. For chapter $III$ and $IV$ on
the group of rational points and cubic curves over finite fields, more algebra is needed (for example, for the proof of Mordell's theorem). For chapters $V$ and $VI$ on Integer points on cubic curves, and Complex multiplication, Galois representations, algebraic number theory, and algebraic geometry would be helpful.